# Generic function to iterate jSon data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am writing a generic function to iterate a jSon file as below:

```
function test(data, type) {
    var k = 0;

    for (var i in data) {
        k += isNaN(data[i].type) ? 0 : data[i].type;
    }

    return (k / data.length);
}
```

where `type` is a dynamic value - it can be "steps", "distance", "floors" etc

What I want to do is that every time when I call the function, it should find what `type` is and find the average for that type. Is there a way to do that?

jSon file is below:

```
[
  {
    "ActivitySummaryKey": 23323,
    "activitycalories": 768,
    "caloriesBMR": 1052,
    "caloriesOut": 1622,
    "distances": 4.14,
    "elevation": 24,
    "fairlyActiveminutes": 62,
    "floors": 8,
    "lightlyActiveMinutes": 125,
    "marginalCalories": 476,
    "sedentaryMinutes": 258,
    "steps": 5547,
    "veryActiveMinutes": 11,
    "createddate": "5/27/2014 12:00:00 AM"
  }
]
```

Comment: an example of your "generic" JSON would be handy

Comment: What is `period1` and `period2`. And also post sample jsOn.

Comment: [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), specifically `.parse`, might help you (from [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery?rq=1) on the sidebar).

Comment: so what's the problem,you wrote a function already.

Comment: @mpm : this function will not work as of now, because 'type' has to be resolved dynamically

Comment: @sony you really haven't explained your issue clearly. What do you mean by `'type' has to be resolved dynamically`. You have `type` as an argument of your function but haven't identified results you are looking for

Comment: Clearly the OP is trying to use the value of the `type` variable as property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to modify your function to use `type` as the property name instead of directly accessing the data at `.type`.

```
function test(data, type) {
    var k = 0;

    for (var i in data) {
        k += isNaN(data[i][type]) ? 0 : data[i][type];
    }

    return (k / data.length);
}
```

Comment: Should be `[type]`, not `['type']`.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for... thaks so much!!! :)

Comment: @FelixKling Oops, you're right. Fixed.